# Git Hub client for Mac doesn't link to my account

Tags: macos, github

I was using Git Hub for windows before ( https://windows.github.com/ )

and all my commits were being properly recorded under my name.

Recently I switched to Mac and started using the client for Mac ( https://mac.github.com/ ).

I logged into the client using my Git Hub credentials, and everything is working as it should. But when I re-view my commits from github.com, changes committed from the Mac client are not linked to my account. Also instead of the username it shows my full name which I supplied while installing the client on Mac. But it is not clickable (it should link to my account).

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else face the same problem it can be solved by typing,

```
$ git config --global user.name "type username here"

$ git config --global user.email "type your email address here"
```

on the terminal.